# Time Complexity of Sort() extension using with CompareTo

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

I know that Sort and OrderBy uses the same sorting algorith which is quicksort. Although Sort() uses unstable, OrderBy() uses stable version. But, that's not the case for me. When I test my code, I achieved the results below for 10000 and 20000 records. Now, I need to callculate time complexity Big(o) of SortByDescending and OrderByDescending methods. How can I?

```
static void main{
     for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            int val = 10000*i;
            Test(val);
        }
}
 public static void Time(int size) {
        List<Test> list = new List<Test>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Test(GenerateX(i), GenerateY(i + 1), RandomDay()));
        }

        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        SortByDescending(list);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Sort By Descending with {0} records: {1} ms",size, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        var watch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        OrderByDescending(list);
        Console.WriteLine("Order By Descending with {0} records: {1}ms",size, watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch2.Stop();


        list.Clear();
    }



 static void SortByDescending(List<Person> list)
    {
        list.Sort((p1, p2) => -1 * p1.Date.CompareTo(p2.Date));
    }

static void OrderByDescending(List<Person> list)
{
    var result = list.OrderByDescending(n => n.Date);
}
```

Comment: For benchmarking I use this: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html

Comment: The complexity is `O(N.Log(N))` average case and `O(N^2)` worst case. If you're trying to calculate the O complexity empirically, you'll have to get in to timing lots of different samples and doing some curve-fitting... But I'm struggling to see the point of that!

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ad8ca31d97eb14b8 and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,70b76524db93e785 the source for Sort/orderby and the Quicksort is also there

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8, Sort uses QuickSort algorithm in most of the cases. So complexity on average is O(N log(N)). Also, QuickSort could show a bad performance up to O(N^2) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), depends on data. Also, Sort might use HeapSort which has complexity O(N log(N)).

Comment: And O cheat Sheet = > https://www.bigocheatsheet.com, for Time and space complexity

Answer (score 1):

I think both algorithm will still have the same Big(O) which is O(n^2) worst case according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort.

This value will not change unless you do a mayor change in the code which change loops, recursions and iterations, and that's not happening in this case. We can call this difference as "micro optimizations" that will not impact our result.

Big O will still be the same as before.